# Tailwind classes are not applying on AntD button in a component library

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, antd, rollupjs, npm-package

I'm developing component library using AntD and Tailwind-css in react with storybook.
I'm overwriting the styles of antd components , Its working fine on local App and on storybook.
But after bundling the build using rollup , when component is published on npm and used on another app it showing the default styles on antd component not the tailwind styles

**Button.tsx**

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority";
import { Button as AntButton, ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import { ButtonProps } from "../../types";

const ButtonStyles = cva(
  "text-center rounded-lg p-0 font-montserrat font-font-medium",
  {
    variants: {
      color: {
        primary:
          "bg-[#445C80] text-white text-base shadow-[rgba(0,_0,_0,_0.25)_0px_0px_4px] hover:bg-[#7F9DC6] focus:bg-[#7F9DC6] focus:shadow-inner focus:shadow-[rgb(127,_157,_198,_0.25)] disabled:bg-[#A1ADBE] disabled:shadow-none disabled:border-none",
        secondary:
          "bg-white text-[#445C80] shadow-[rgba(0,_0,_0,_0.25)_0px_0px_4px] hover:bg-[#EDEBED] focus:bg-[#EDEBED] focus:shadow-inner focus:shadow-[rgb(237,_235,_237,_0.25)] active:border-2 active:border-[#445C80]",
      },
      size: {
        mobile: "h-[48px] w-[128px] text-base",
        desktop: "h-[33px] w-[128px] text-sm",
        tablet: "h-[28px] w-[82px] text-xs",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      color: "secondary",
      size: "desktop",
    },
  }
);

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  label,
  color = "primary",
  size = "desktop",
  disabled = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider>
<AntButton className={ButtonStyles({ color, size})}  {...props} disabled={disabled} type="primary" >
        {label}
      </AntButton>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

**index.css**

```
@import 'antd/dist/reset.css';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto&display=swap");

.ant-btn-primary{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

> Importing Index.css on index.ts file which imports/export all
> components.

**Rollup Config file**

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

const rollupConfig = [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/cjs/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
      },
      {
        file: "dist/esm/index.js",
        format: "esm",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss({
        plugins: [],
      }),
      terser(),
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'antd'], // Add other external dependencies here
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];

export default rollupConfig;
```

What i'm doing wrong which is not applying tailwind classes in npm package.

Comment: It could be a specifity issue. Can you inspect the component in dev tools and see the antd styles taking priority over the npm package styles?